# Why does this solution say that "the total charge is" \$\Delta q\$, when \$\Delta q\$ actually is the difference/change in charge?

Tags: charge

I'm currently studying the textbook *Fundamentals of Electric Circuits*, 7th edition, by Charles Alexander and Matthew Sadiku. Chapter **1.5 Power and Energy** gives the following example:

> **Example 1.4**
>
> An energy source forces a constant current of 2 A for 10 s to flow through a light bulb. If 2.3 kJ is given off in the form of light and heat energy, calculate the voltage drop across the bulb.
>
> **Solution:**
>
> The total charge is
> $$\Delta q = i \Delta t = 2 \times 10 = 20 \text{ C}$$
> The voltage drop is
> $$\nu = \dfrac{\Delta w}{\Delta q} = \dfrac{2.3 \times 10^3}{20} = 115 \text{ V}$$

Why does this solution say that "the total charge is" \$\Delta q\$, when \$\Delta q\$ actually is the difference/change in charge? I'm not sure whether I'm missing something here, or whether it's just an unusual choice of words.

Comment: the word 'total' seems superfluous here, suggesting a disctinction where none exists. It's a loose and lazy use of language, beacuse, as you've demonstrated, it's obvious what the author actually means in the context.

Comment: @Neil_UK Ok, thanks for the clarification. I guess we just trust in the mathematics, since that, unlike natural language, is unambiguous.

Comment: It could have an initial charge, and after 10s it is not fully discharged, so there is also the remaining charge, thus difference of charge.

Comment: Between what position/time is the *difference taken* ? I think the word "*total*" is appropriate since that is the total charge that passed through the light bulb during the conduct of the experiment. The word "*difference*" would be okay to use if we were talking about the charge imbalance between two plates of a capacitor or comparing the charge on an object at two different time instants.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for the input.

Answer (score 0):

It's steady state problem. No transient calculations are requested.

Δq is the total charge that flows in the bulb in Δt time interval.